# How would I use Mathematica to solve this? New to the platform

Tags: functions

Take f(x) = x^2 and Δx = 0.1.
a. Compute the first forward, backward and central differences at x = 1, 2,..., 100. Compare the ouput against the actual derivative. Compute the mean absolute error for each case.
b. Which finite difference procedure is better? Why?
c. Compute the second central difference at the given locations. Compare the output against the actual second derivatives and compute the mean absolute error.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is `x2` `x^2`? What have you tried? Edit your question and add the code you have tried and the issues you encountered.

Comment: Yes it is x^2, sorry about that. Also I haven't tried any code yet, stuck on the question overall as I'm new to the platform.

Comment: If you are new to WL you should learn the basics first. A good place to start is the free online [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/index.html) by Stephen Wolfram the inventor of the language.

Answer (score 5):

I was going to answer the whole question but I see it will be closed. So here is what I have to far.

If it says open, will finish later.

Your function $x^2$ is not too interesting, so I am using different function, but you can change that

```
ClearAll[f,x,h]
f[x_]:=Sin[x];
h=1/10;
forwardDiff[f_,x_,h_]:=(f[x+h]-f[x])/h
backwardDiff[f_,x_,h_]:=(f[x]-f[x-h])/h
centralDiff[f_,x_,h_]:=(f[x+h]-f[x-h])/(2*h)

(*this uses point/slope method to find equation of line to plot*)
equationOfLine[x0_, y0_, slope_, var_] := Module[{b},
  b = y0 - slope*x0;
  slope*var + b
  ]
```

Lets compare how good each by plotting the tangent at a point and compare to the real one

```
x0=Pi/2;
y0=f[x0];
actualTangent=equationOfLine[x0,y0,(D[f[x],x])/.x->x0,x];
forwardDiffTangent=equationOfLine[x0,y0,forwardDiff[f,x0,h],x];
backwardDiffTangent=equationOfLine[x0,y0,backwardDiff[f,x0,h],x];
centralDiffTangent=equationOfLine[x0,y0,centralDiff[f,x0,h],x];

Plot[{f[x], Callout[actualTangent, "actual"], 
  Callout[forwardDiffTangent, "foward"], 
  Callout[backwardDiffTangent, "backward"], 
  Callout[centralDiffTangent, "centered"]}, {x, x0 - h, x0 + h}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Comparing the tangent line using different derivative method"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see that centered different gives best approximation to real tangent.

Now we can generate the first table (only 10 points , you can change that)

```
data = N@
   Table[{x0, (D[f[x], x]) /. x -> x0, forwardDiff[f, x0, h], 
     backwardDiff[f, x0, h], centralDiff[f, x0, h]}, {x0, 1, 10, 1}];
PrependTo[
  data, {"point", "actual derivative", "forward drivative", 
   "backward derivative", "centered derivative"}];
Grid[data, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To find mean absolute error, using the formula from Wikipedia (may be there is a build in function for this already in Mathematica)

[image]

Applying the above gives

```
n = 10;
data = Table[{x0, (D[f[x], x]) /. x -> x0, forwardDiff[f, x0, h], 
    backwardDiff[f, x0, h], centralDiff[f, x0, h]}, {x0, 1, n, 1}];
MAEfowardDiff = Sum[Abs[data[[m, 2]] - data[[m, 3]]  ], {m, 1, n} ]/n // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MAEbackwardDiff = Sum[Abs[data[[m, 2]] - data[[m, 4]]  ], {m, 1, n} ]/n // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 MAEcenteredDiff =  Sum[Abs[data[[m, 2]] - data[[m, 5]]  ], {m, 1, n} ]/n // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This shows that centered difference has smallest mean absolute error as expected.

To Show this more clearly, here is a small Manipulate. This shows that as $h$ gets smaller, all three finite difference method becomes closer to the actual derivative. It also shows this depends on the point location. This uses $\sin(x)$ but you can change this to any other function.

[image]

---

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y0, x, forwardDiffSlope, backwardDiffSlope, centralDiffSlope,
    actualTangentLine, forwardDiffTangent, backwardDiffTangent, 
   centralDiffTangent, b, actualSlope, f},
  f[x_] := Sin[x];
  y0 = f[x0];
  forwardDiffSlope = (f[x0 + h] - f[x0])/h;
  backwardDiffSlope = (f[x0] - f[x0 - h])/h;
  centralDiffSlope = (f[x0 + h] - f[x0 - h])/(2*h);
  actualSlope = (D[f[x], x]) /. x -> x0;
  
  b = y0 - actualSlope*x0;
  actualTangentLine = actualSlope*x + b;
  
  b = y0 - forwardDiffSlope*x0 ;
  forwardDiffTangent = forwardDiffSlope*x + b;
  
  b = y0 - backwardDiffSlope*x0 ;
  backwardDiffTangent = backwardDiffSlope*x + b;
  
  b = y0 - centralDiffSlope*x0 ;
  centralDiffTangent = centralDiffSlope*x + b;
  
  Grid[{
    {Plot[{f[x], Callout[actualTangentLine, "actual"],
       Callout[forwardDiffTangent, "foward"],
       Callout[backwardDiffTangent, "backward"],
       Callout[centralDiffTangent, "centered"]
       },
      {x, x0 - 2 h, x0 + 2 h},
      PlotLabel -> 
       "Comparing the tangent line using different methods",
      PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Green, Red, Blue, Magenta},
      ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {y0 - h/2, y0 + h/2}},
      Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed,
        Line[{{x0 - h, y0 - h/2}, {x0 - h, f[x0 - h]}}],
        Line[{{x0 + h, y0 - h/2}, {x0 + h, f[x0 + h]}}],
        Line[{{x0, y0 - h/2}, {x0, f[x0]}}]
        }
      ]
     }}
   ]
  ]
 ,
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{x0, Pi/2, "point ?"}, Pi/4, 3/4*Pi, .01, 
      ControlType -> Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{h, .7, "h ?"}, .01, 1, .01, ControlType -> Slider, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}
   }],
 TrackedSymbols :> {f, x0, h},
 
 
 ControlPlacement -> Top
 
 ]
```

Comment: Hi Nasser. You are amazing! I have learned an infinite numbers of things from your answers and also your website!

Comment: thanks @Marteen. We all learn from each others here :)